# BuferredIO and ImmediateFlush properties in Logback configuration

Tags: java, logging, logback, logback-classic

I'm migrating a legacy app to Spring Boot and I've faced with the following problem: when I start the app it fails because of the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback
>   configuration error detected:                           ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@10:21 - no applicable action
>   for [BufferedIO], current ElementPath  is
>   [[configuration][appender][BufferedIO]]
>   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:25 - no
>   applicable action for [ImmediateFlush], current ElementPath  is
>   [[configuration][appender][ImmediateFlush]]
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:161)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:207)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:65)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:50)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:114)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:299)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:272)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:235)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:208)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:72)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:338)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:309)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1187)
>   at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1176)
>   at com.some_company.SomeApp.main(SomeApp.java:28)

So Logback can't resolve BuferredIO and ImmediateFlush properties. I've tried to see their [docs](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) but it seems to be out-of-date as it says such properties exist + I've found e.g. for `OutputStreamAppender` that it doesn't have the `immediateFlush` property while according to the docs it should.

I can't find any info on if Logback still supports the following properties now. Could you please help and suggest some ideas on how I can achieve the same result as with the properties previously? Maybe they are somewhere else:)

Thank you very much!:)

**UPDATE:** Adding a Logback configuration snapshot:

```
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>${logdir}/some-app.log</File>
        <Append>true</Append>        
        <BufferedIO>false</BufferedIO>
        <ImmediateFlush>true</ImmediateFlush>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${logdir}/archive-some-app.%i.log.zip</FileNamePattern>
            <MinIndex>1</MinIndex>
            <MaxIndex>10</MaxIndex>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>20MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>

        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <timestamp>timestamp</timestamp>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Logback version is 1.1.7 (was previously before the migration)

Comment: Showing your logback.xml would help.

Comment: In addition to posting your `logback.xml`, could you also state what version of Logback you are using?

Comment: @Ondřej Xicht Světlík How could I forget, thanks, added:)

Comment: @glytching sure, thanks for the note, please, the the updated question

Comment: Apparently, in 1.1.7 none of these two options is present. I found immediateFlush in 1.2.3 and bufferedIO in 0.9.7 or something like this. I have no idea on which version the documentation is based, but the date of last update (in 2008 which corresponds with the 0.9.x version) gives us a clue. 1.1.7 is from 2016 and 1.2.3 is from 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `ImmediateFlush` is a valid configuration property for [OutputStreamAppender](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#OutputStreamAppender) (which `RollingFileAppender` extends) in the latest version of Logback (and hence is referenced in the latest docs) this was only added to `OutputStreamAppender` [here](https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/commit/e2a9429c293ddc55b2a0f771c376b1bf3b00c8ba#diff-086cf7ac59ca30c9c8e6a601a25f939b) in Feb 2017. So, `immediateFlush` is not a valid property of `OutputStreamAppender` (and hence is inaccessible from `RollingFileAppender`) in v1.1.7

This explains the following error:

> no applicable action for [ImmediateFlush], current ElementPath is [[configuration][appender][ImmediateFlush]]

[`BufferedIO`](http://dev.cs.ovgu.de/java/logback/manual/appenders.html) is an old configuration property which is no longer supported by Logback.

This explains the following error:

> no applicable action for [BufferedIO], current ElementPath is [[configuration][appender][BufferedIO]]

In summary, you might consider upgrading to the latest Logback and just remove `<BufferedIO>false</BufferedIO>`. Or, continue to use v1.1.7 and remove both of these: `<BufferedIO>false</BufferedIO>` and `<ImmediateFlush>true</ImmediateFlush>`.

Comment: seems like an answer. however, I've found `BufferedIO` [here](http://dev.cs.ovgu.de/java/logback/manual/appenders.html)

Comment: As I said before, the documentation is based on 0.9.x version. It's way too old.

Comment: Good spot. Given the footer there ("Copyright © 2000-2007") that looks like a static grab of very old Logback docs. So that explains where BufferedIO came from. Anyway, it is no longer supported by Logback so I think the recommendation to remove that line from your logback.xml is valid.

Comment: @DmitrySenkovich I have updated the answer to include the link to the old docs which include BufferedIO, thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @Ondřej Xicht Světlík oh, ok, sorry, got it now:) thank you very much, now I see, thanks!